# C# MSword doesnt highlight whole word when using Find and matchAllWordForms=true

Tags: c#, ms-word, selection, highlight, replace

In my program, I'm using `Find.Execute` to search for all the word forms of a keyword and highlight them. For example, If my source document contains "perform" and "performance", `Find.Execute(...matchAllWordForms=true...)` will find both words, but it will only highlight the 'perform' section of performance.

How can I get MSWord to highlight the entire word? The `range.Text` is changed by `Find.Execute` to just be "perform", so I cant iterate through that. I tried doing a `Range.Select()` and then iterating `Selection.End`, but the ranges do no match up with the original document.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I feel kind of stupid:

I was trying to use `Selection.Extend` and completely missed the `Selection.Expand` option. For anyone who stumbles across this later:

```
range.Select();    // The range after Find.Execute
wordApp.Selection.Expand(Word.WdUnits.wdWord);    // may have to trim off excess whitespace
Word.Range highlightRange = document.Range(wordApp.Selection.Start, wordApp.Selection.End);
wordApp.Selection.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = (Word.WdColor)System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(extractedColor);
```

Note that I use Shading for my highlighter (so I can create custom colors with `System.Drawing.Color.FromARGB(Alpha,R,G,B)` instead of the default 15 colors).

Comment: Hello @Chris, welcome at StackOverflow! If this is the solution to your problem please do not forget to mark it as the correct answer. Then we all can see if there is a solution at all. :-)

Comment: yup, just waiting for the wait timer to expire